How to Enable Dual Monitor Display on Vivobook 15 M513 Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I have a Vivobook 15 M513 (AMD Radeon Graphics) laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and encounter issues with connecting a second monitor via USB-C for display. The primary monitor works fine with HDMI, but the USB-C connection doesn't function. I suspect it might be a driver issue or compatibility problem with my laptop's USB-C port. Any recommendations on resolving this to enable dual monitor display?
